# gibberish instead of html response as body in node.request

Tags: node.js, http, curl

I'm making a HTTP request to a password protected site using the request module in npm, putting in a password, storing a cookie, then making the request once the cookie is stored and verified. I am able to get the same headers as I would on a normal browser request, but hte body itself, instead of being the HTML document I get in a browser, just looks like this:

�      �Z�r�H��c��䞙��pT���Ī$3�ƾ�~Y�@�MK8���>*��?�z)�?U���ݨ�J�혳��섯tB��x��c��?�����������0�H�����V��O'�7����}���L�"˖}/ta�xn�g#�ݱ�O�����

Any ideas what might be causing this or how I can fix it?

In addition, when I run this from the command prompt, the computer "dings"

Here is the full node.js code I am running (minus the URLs/passwords/etc.)

```
var parsedurl1 = url.parse( urlstring1 );
var options1 = {
  hostname: parsedurl1.hostname,
  port: ( parsedurl1.port || 80 ), // 80 by default
  method: 'POST',
  path: parsedurl1.path,
  headers: { 
      'Host': hostname
      ,'User-Agent': myuseragent
      ,'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
      ,'Accept-Language':"en-US,en;q=0.5"
      ,'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate"
      ,'Referer': hostname
      ,'Content-Type': "text/html; charset=utf-8"
      ,'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
      ,'Connection': "keep-alive"
      ,'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1"},
};
var cookiefile ; 
var postData=querystring.stringify({
        'email': myemail
        ,'password':mypassword
        ,'action': 'login'
        ,'go.x': 0
        ,'go.y': 0
    })
var cookiefile;
var callback =  function ( response ) {
    // display returned cookies in header
    var setcookie = response.headers["set-cookie"];
    if ( setcookie ) {
      setcookie.forEach(
        function ( cookiestr ) {
             cookiefile = cookiestr;
             fs.writeFile(cookiefilelocation, cookiestr);
          console.log(  "COOKIE:" + cookiestr );
        }
      );
    }    
    var data = "";
    response.on(
      "data",
      function ( chunk ) { data += chunk; }
    );

    response.on(
      "end",
      function () {  
            newcookiefile =  cookiefile.substr(0, cookiefile.indexOf(";"));
            var parsedurl2 = url.parse( urlstring2 );
            var options2 = {
                url: urlstring2,
                // port: ( parsedurl2.port || 80 ), // 80 by default
                method: 'GET',
                // path: parsedurl2.path,
                headers: { 
                "Host": hostname
                ,"User-Agent": myuseragent
                ,'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
                ,'Accept-Language':"en-US,en;q=0.5"
                ,'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate"
                ,'Referer':hostname
                ,'Cookie': newcookiefile
                ,'Connection': "keep-alive"
                ,'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1"},
            };

            function callback3(error, response, body){
                console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred 

                console.log('statusCode:', response.headers ); // Print the response status code if a response was received 
                console.log('body:', body.substr(1,1000));
                fs.writeFile('./config/pullfiles/mostrecent.txt', body);
                }
            requestlib(options2, callback3);
      }
    );
  };
var request = http.request(options1, callback);


request.on(
  "error",
  function( err ) {
    console.error( "RERROR:" + err );
  }
);
request.write(postData);
request.end(); // let request know it is finished sending
```

Comment: Your computer dings because of a byte containing `0x07`, which is the "bell" character code.  (A lot more relevant from the days of teletype.)  In any case, with no code at all, no packet capture to inspect, not even a URL to try ourselves, it's impossible to help you.  You're looking at a bunch of binary data from something.

Comment: Ok I am updating now with more info - sorry there wasn't enough before

Comment: @Brad I have added my full code - please let me know if this is still not written up to standard and I will close and rewrite the question. Thank you

Comment: It's not about writing to a standard, it's about giving relevant information so people can actually help you...

Comment: OK well thank you. I have added the code. I do not know how to give a packet capture.

Comment: Download Wireshark.  (There are other similar tools if you don't want to use Wireshark for some reason, but Wireshark is one of the best.)  Start capturing data on whatever network interface your app is using to make its requests to the other server.  Run your app.  Stop the capture.  In the filter box, put in something like `tcp.port eq 80`.  (Use whatever port the request was sent over.)  Scroll through the packets until you see an HTTP GET request for the right path.  Right click, hit "following conversation".  Then you'll see what actually was sent over the wire.

Comment: I am trying to do this on Wireshark but frankly even following the conversation there are too many requests to and fro. Like hundreds. Thank you for trying at least.  It wasn't nearly this hard in PHP -- I can give up making this work in node.js

Comment: The problem in PHP is identical as it is in Node.js...  You should know the path you're requesting, so it shouldn't be hard to skim through the list and find the one that pertains to your HTTP request.  You can also resolve the hostname and then filter by IP address.  `ip.addr eq 10.1.2.3.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148095/discussion-between-garson-and-brad).

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out! This gibberish was caused by my lack of the 'gzip: true' option is my request(). Now the second request reads:

```
url: urlstring2
    ,gzip: true
    ,headers:{...
```